# How do I deposit a USD check into a US bank account by mail from abroad?

Tags: united-states, check

Forgive me for what is probably quite an obvious question for anyone who understands the US banking system, but I don't.

I live in the UK, and I have a check in US dollars I need to do something with. Somewhat conveniently I have a US bank account dating from some time I spent working in the US about 10 years ago, so I'd like to pay it in to that to avoid the fees for negotiating it in the UK. I guess I should mail it to the bank, but what other information should I include?

I have a bunch of "deposit tickets" in the back of my checkbook, which also is about 10 years old, so I guess I could fill one of those in.

I'm also a bit confused by when and how you need to "endorse" a check.

I've left this a bit late - only have about a month left before the 6 month limit on the check expires - so need to get it right first time.

Comment: different banks have different options. Call up your bank customer service and ask them what to do. They'll probably give you much better instructions than you would ever find here.

Comment: Be aware that if you have not _used_ your US account recently (meaning within the past year or two), and especially if the amount you left in it was small, it may have been treated as a _dormant account_ and turned over to the State in which the bank is located.

Comment: I'm still getting statements and can log into the account online. I just can't use their online check deposit because for some reason you need a credit card from them to do that.

Comment: Depositing checks to a bank account is surprisingly easy to do, if your name is on the account and the check is made out to you. I once had someone I was consulting for mail checks in directly to my bank -- which deposited them, un-endorsed and everything. Granted, it was a small local bank and they knew me...

Comment: Most banks allow depositing checks via your phone.  You can just scan the image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would call your bank directly and ask if they can mail you deposit slips or if they have deposit slips available to print off online.  Wrap your check and completed deposit slip in a piece of paper so that the information is not visible through the envelope or packaging you are using, and ask them for a receipt when it is received.  As far as endorsement, you should write "For deposit only" and sign your name underneath in the area of the back of the check for endorsements.  This will ensure that the check is deposited into your account and cannot be cashed if it is intercepted in the mail.

Comment: another option to consider is using a mobile application to deposit the check. That way you won't be mailing anything anywhere. Most major US banks (with a notable exception of Wells Fargo) allow that.

Comment: Unfortunately their online check deposit is for some reason tied to have a credit card from them, which I don't.

Answer (score 1):

If the bank has not changed  and your account number is still the same then you should be able to use the deposit slips in the back of your check book.  Your checks may no longer be valid but your bank does not need a valid routing number to deposit your check.  Most banks will accept deposits if the Account number is included in the endorsement.